# Difference between spring.jpa.properties.hibernate and spring.jpa.hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a `Spring Boot` project and using `Spring Data JPA` with `Hibernate` as `JPA` implementation.

Currently in my `application.yml` file I have the following properties:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: true
                generate_statistics: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

There are Hibernate properties with different prefixes(`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate` and `spring.jpa.hibernate`)

What is the purpose of having these difference and can they be used interchangeably, meaning can I replace `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql` with `spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql`?

Comment: Just a quick guess is that one set is passed into hibernate configuration and the other is used by Spring code, hence the split, but the simple answer is to look at the source code (I'll have a look when I have my laptop on later if nobody else has given a clear answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is explained in the Spring Boot Reference Documentation at [Configure JPA Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties):

> -- all properties in `spring.jpa.properties.*` are passed through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the local EntityManagerFactory is created.

So, `spring.jpa.hibernate.X` properties are used by Spring, and `spring.jpa.properties` are passed on to whatever JPA implementation you are using, allowing you to set configuration properties that Spring does not have.

Comment: Can all properties of `spring.jpa.hibernate.X` be placed in `spring.jpa.properties.hiberante.X`? What does spring has to do with `spring.jpa.hiberante.X` properties?

Comment: Could someone, please, provide a link to documentation of possible `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate` properties? Upd.: [found it](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html) ^_^

Answer (score -2):

For simplification, there are no more than convention, exactly. Just care about `value` of `key`.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

are the same.

For more information, you can see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy just for easy for remember something.

> In addition, all properties in spring.jpa.properties.* are passed
> through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the
> local EntityManagerFactory is created.

(source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties)

Comment: I see no difference between the two, other than reordering of properties.